# Grant users from CloudSQL instance IAM permissions to Cloud Storage objects

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-iam

I have a question about GCP and this Django app I am making. I am using Google cloud storage to hold documents that I need to provide access permissions for to my users, but I can't think of how to link users from my app (being saved to CloudSQL-PostgresSQL) to my Google Cloud project.

This feels like it should be an easy case to handle, but i'm used to services like Cognito handling this for me.

Should I make a service account for every user?

Comment: what kind of permissions should they have? did you took a look to [signed url's](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls)

Comment: You can't create a service account per user. You are limited to 100 service account per project, and it won't solve your issue. Is this answer can help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62532907/authorization-and-authentication-mechanism-in-gcp/62542120#62542120

Comment: Thank you both, using a separate table to manage who gets what videos and then simply generating a singed URL for a user when they want to view a document is a really good idea. The article dd help too